# Bash script, if C++ returns something

Tags: c++, bash, debian

I've got a custom C++ application, which return 0 if everything is OK and printf(...) if something goes wrong.

I've also got a bash script (running as cronjob) which needs to check the execution of the C++ application.

How can I in a bash:

```
if ./run_app; then
else
fi
```

check if it returns 0 or some other text?

```
if ./run_app = 0; then
```

doesn't work.

UPDATE:

My actual code in C++ looks like this when everything goes well:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    ...
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does it return 0 when something goes wrong also? Is it **completely** silent (no output at all) when it works?

Comment: Do you mean that it returns `0` from `main()`, or that it outputs `0` to stdout?

Comment: It is completely silent when everything goes correctly. I return 0 from the main(), NOT stdout..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the application returns 0 on success and non-0 on failure, then the first form of

```
if ./run_app; then
else
fi
```

Will work.

Comment: My main() returns 0 when everything goes correctly. Running the application in the console returns nothing. But when I print out $? in the console it shows "1", not "0".

Comment: Found this http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html, so I'll start debugging...

Answer (score 3):

You could also do:

```
./run_app
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
```

as `$?` captures the return value of the last program.

Answer (score 2):

Use test(1).

e.g.

```
result=$(my_application)
backup=$?

[ -z "$result" ] && echo "my_application printed nothing"
[ $backup -eq 0 ] && echo "my_application returned zero"
```